# Cannot open database error in Windows Server 2012

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, iis, windows-server-2012

I'm trying to host my website in Windows Server 2012, I've configured everything and placed my site folder in `wwwroot`, when I launch from the IIS as a localhost I get this error at start,

> Cannot open database "rental_db" requested by the login. The login failed.
> Login failed for user 'IIS APPPOOL\mysitename.com'.

I've used Windows Authentication to login in sql server and I can access it properly. I'm not sure what is actually causing the problem. Here is the connection string code of **web.config**,

```
<add name="rental_dbEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/Models.rentalModel.csdl|res://*/Models.rentalModel.ssdl|res://*/Models.rentalModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=MYSERVER2012\SQLINSTANCENAME;initial catalog=rental_db;integrated security=True;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
```

Note: I've shifted my published project folder from my desktop to server. Why is this happening?

Answer (score 2):

You need create on your IIS App_Pool with the same name, and create in your SQL Server the user with all privileges.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't know how to do it since this is the first time I'm hosting in Windows Server, detailed guidance would be really helpful.

Comment: @SinOscuras now i'm at work, when i go at home i try attach any screenshot

Comment: Ok. Thank you so much.